# Combining the output of three functions in a class and then displaying the final output

Tags: php

I am trying to understand how classes and functions work. I am trying to do an example of just adding two different variables together to form one and then output it.

There are 3 functions inside the class - one for generating a random number, the other for generating a random word and the last for combining the output of those both functions.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php
class generateTicket
{

    public function numbers()
    {
        $randomnum = number_format(random_int(1000, 9999) / 100, 2);
    }


    public function words()
    {
        $randomword = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8));
    }

    public function combined()
    {
        $A = $this->numbers($randomnum);
        $B = $this->words($randomword);
        echo $A . "-" . $B;
    }

}

$class = new generateTicket();
$class->combined();
?>
```

Comment: Read: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Comment: @LioraHaydont 
`Notice: Undefined variable: randomnum` and
`Notice: Undefined variable: randomword`

Comment: Your methods `numbers()` and `words()` don't take any arguments and you are passing them argument, where you don't use them ?

Comment: In addition to Sammitch's comment, also read: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing unknown variables in your combined method.
$randomnum and $randomword are undefined in the below lines:

```
public function combined()
{
    $A = $this->numbers($randomnum);
    $B = $this->words($randomword);
    echo $A . "-" . $B;
}
```

You have a couple of options here:

One option is to return the variables:

```
public function numbers()
{
    return number_format(random_int(1000, 9999) / 100, 2);
}


public function words()
{
    return bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8));
}

public function combined()
{
    $A = $this->numbers();
    $B = $this->words();
    echo $A . "-" . $B;
}
```

Another option would be as follows:

```
public function numbers()
{
    $this->randomnum = number_format(random_int(1000, 9999) / 100, 2);
}


public function words()
{
    $this->randomword = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8));
}

public function combined()
{
    $this->numbers();
    $this->words();
    echo $this->randomnum . "-" . $this->randomword;
}
```